# parse time diff and divide mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, statistics, quartz-scheduler, aggregate-functions

I have a query that I have used to determine when a quartz job. I'm trying to devise a way to determine when a quartz job has fallen behind or gotten stuck. The issue is the jobs vary in time intervals so I want to be able to use a "greater than X standard deviations" logic when determining when the job is broken. Is there a way to do this within mysql? It would basically be:

(previous_fire_time - next_fire_time) / timeinterval = X deviations

```
select job_group, job_name, 
       from_unixtime(prev_fire_time / 1000) prev,
       from_unixtime(next_fire_time / 1000) next, 
       sec_to_time((next_fire_time - prev_fire_time) / 1000) diff
  from qrtz_triggers;
```

```
+-----------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| job_group | job_name               | prev                     | next                     | diff           |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| jon       |  media                 | 2016-02-25 15:50:30.0000 | 2016-02-25 16:50:30.0000 | 01:00:00.0000  |
| jon       | ListUpdater            | 2016-02-25 15:36:00.0000 | 2016-02-25 16:06:00.0000 | 00:30:00.0000  |
| jon       | Resolver               | 2016-02-25 05:00:00.0000 | 2016-02-26 05:00:00.0000 | 24:00:00.0000  |
| dan       | Resubmitter            | 2016-02-25 15:55:30.0000 | 2016-02-25 16:55:30.0000 | 01:00:00.0000  |
| admin     | NetworkExecutor        | 2016-02-25 06:10:00.0000 | 2016-02-26 06:10:00.0000 | 24:00:00.0000  |   | admin     | AUpdater                          | 2016-02-21 03:00:00.0000 | 2016-02-28 03:00:00.0000 | 168:00:00.0000 |
| admin     | alexaweb               | 2016-02-25 15:55:36.0000 | 2016-02-25 15:56:36.0000 | 00:01:00.0000  |
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers the aggregate function [`STDDEV()` and some variants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html), along with a bunch of other statistical functions.

If you want the average (the arithmetic mean) and standard deviation of a bunch of time intervals from `start` to `end`, you do this:

```
  SELECT AVG(end-start) mean,  STDDEV(end-start) stddev
    FROM table
```

If you want to find the rows in the table that have a duration more than two standard deviations above the mean, you do this...

```
  SELECT table.* 
    FROM table
   WHERE (end-start) > ( SELECT (AVG(end-start) + (2.0 * STDDEV(end-start))) 
                   FROM table )
```

That should get you started.

I did a bunch of this kind of stuff once. I found that it was necessary to get quite a large dataset of "normal" observations before I could reliably compute the number of standard deviations that constituted an abnormal observation. I also found that *small* durations were a big indication of trouble: these were the jobs that crapped out (that's a technical term) before they were done.

Finally, I think you may be slightly better off using [mean absolute deviation rather than standard deviation](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/mean-absolute-deviation/). It's less sensitive to extreme outliers.